# QNetworkAccessManager issue

Tags: c++, qt, httprequest, qnetworkaccessmanager, get-request

```
QString My_class::My_Method()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(ReplayFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(My_URL)));
    return str;
}

void My_class::ReplayFinished(QNetworkReply *replay)
{
    QString buffer;
    if(replay->isOpen())
    {
        buffer=replay->readAll();
//treatment on the buffer and the public Qstring 'str'(declared in My_class.h) is updated
    }
}
```

Hi,
the problem is that when calling the My_method() in the main, the `QString str` is empty because it was returned that way without waiting for the ReplayFinished to update it.
What could be the solution to wait until the job is complete so I can get the proper information, not skipping it and returning something else.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an event loop to wait until the reply is finished and then read the available bytes and return the string :

```
QString My_class::My_Method()
{

   QNetworkAccessManager manager;

   QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(My_URL)));

   QEventLoop loop;
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   loop.exec();

   QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
   QString str(bts);

   delete reply;

   return str;

}
```

Comment: I don't think this solution is good enough. What will happen on error? Qt docs say that the `finished` signal "will **probably** follow", but if not, than your event loop will not quit at all. Besides, it is good idea to delete `manager` and `reply` objects afterwards.